In how many ways can the numbers $1,$ $2,$ $3,$ $4,$ $5,$ $6$ be arranged in a row, so that the product of any two adjacent numbers is even?
In how many ways can the numbers $1,$ $2,$ $3,$ $4,$ $5,$ $6$ be arranged in a row, so that the product of any two adjacent numbers is even?
My Workout: Since any two adjacent numbers is even, the row can be either $EOEOEO$ or $OEOEOE$, where $E$ is for even and $O$ is for odd.
Now $E \in \{2,4,6\}$ so there are $3! = 6$ ways to arrange and same for odd numbers.
Hence we have total of $2*6^2 = 72$ ways to arrange them in a row.

But the answer says its wrong. Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong?
Source: AOPS.

It's not obvious that either approach will be much easier. PIE allows for a systematic way to list (but could trip you up in the counting), and checking all possible cases also works (but you could miss one)

What is the answer given?

@Srini I dont have the answer, its a HW problem from AOPS

Equivalently, how many ways are there for the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ to be arranged in a row so that no two odd numbers are right next to each other? Your answer is incorrect as it does not include the cases where two adjacent numbers are both even.

The numver of possible sets positions for the odd numbers is the number of solutions $a+b+c+d=3$ where $b,c>0$ and $a,d\geq 0.$ This is the number of solutions to $a+b'+c'+d=1$ where $a,b',c',d\geq 0.$ There are obviously four such sets.

@user5210, I am not familiar with AOPS and don't know how you verify your answers. I get 180 as answer, but I don't want to post a wrong answer. By some chance if that is right, I can post it, but I am not confident it is right. Better to wait for experts to respond.

The answer ploosu2 gave is correct, but $144/720 = 1/5$ which screams out for a simpler answer.
If you think about ways to arrange even and odd, then ther are four "good" arrangements of even and odd - EOEOEO, OEEOEO, OEOEEO, OEOEOE - out of a total of ${6 \choose 3} = 20$.  All are equally likely because they correspond to the same number of arrangemnts of individual numbers.  So the answer is $4/20 = 1/5$.

Include-Exclude with the sets $A_j = \{j\text{th and } (j+1) \text{st are odd}\}$. Intersections of three or more are all empty because there aren't enough odd numbers. Also $A_j \cap A_k = \emptyset$ when $j$ and $k$ aren't adjacent. So the answer is
$$
6! - |A_1| - |A_2| - \dots - |A_5| + |A_1\cap A_2| + |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_4 \cap A_5| \\
= 6! - 5\cdot \binom{3}{2}2! 4! + 4\cdot 3!3! = 144.
$$

Consider the odd digits with gaps
$${}- O = O = O -{.}$$
We must place one even digit each in the middle gaps, and the remaining even digit can be placed in any of the $4$ gaps, thus
$$ \text{total valid arrangements} = 4*3!3! =144.$$

For the general problem, you can derive an explicit formula, by first reframing the problem:
Let $f(n)$ denote the solution to your problem for numbers $1,\dots,2n$, and $g(n)$ the solution to your problem for numbers $1,\dots,2n+1$. Suppose we have some valid permutation and we want to add a single number $2n+1$, there is only one place where it can go, so $f(n)=g(n)$.
Now let's observe how valid permutations $1,\dots,2n+1$ look:
As there are $n+1$ odd numbers and $n$ even numbers they must be of the form $OEOEOE\dots O$, so the problem is equivalent to finding how many such permutations there are. Clearly, we can permute $O$s and $E$s separately, so the number of such permutations is $(n+1)!\cdot(n!) = (n+1)(n!)^2$ which is the answer to your problem.
In conclusion $f(n)=g(n)=(n+1)(n!)^2$, so the answer for $2\cdot3$ objects is $f(3) = 4\cdot(6)^2 = 144$.

Alternative approach:
This can be regarded as a Stars and Bars problem in disguise.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.
Consider the following tableau
_ O-1 _ O-2 _ _ O-3

In the above tableau, O-1, O-2, O-3 represent the positions assigned to the three odd numbers.  These positions create $~4~$ islands.  Reading the islands from left to right, let $~x_1, \cdots, x_4~$ denote the size of each of the respective islands.
First of all, reserve the factor of $~A = 3! \times 3!.~$  With this factor in reserve, you can now assume, without loss of generality, that the odd numbers are indistinguishable from each other, and the even numbers are indistinguishable from each other.
Then, there is a bijection between the distribution of the odd numbers, and the size of each of $~x_1, \cdots, x_4.~$
Further, the constraint of no odd products from adjacent terms exactly corresponds to the constraint that $~x_2,x_3~$ are each $~\geq 1.~$
So, with the $~A~$ product reserved, the problem reduces to enumerating the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 3.$ 
That is, each variable $~x_i~$ may represent the placement of $~0~$ or more even numbers.

$~x_1, \cdots, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$~x_2, x_3 \geq 1.$


Basic Stars and Bars theory requires that each variable have a lower bound of $~0.~$ The remedy to the above enumeration problem is $~y_2 = x_2 - 1, ~y_3 = x_3 - 1.$
So, the enumeration portion of the problem is converted to enumerating the number of solutions to

$x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + x_4 = 3 - 2 = 1.$

$~x_1, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$~y_2, y_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


By Stars and Bars theory, the enumeration is 
$\displaystyle \binom{1 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{4}{3} = 4.$
Therefore, the final computation is
$$A \times 4 = 3! \times 3! \times 4 = 144.$$

$~\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
A moderate alternative to the above approach is to retain the Stars and Bars approach, and couple it with the analysis in the answer of Michael Lugo.
This leads to the computation of
$$\frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{6}{3}} \times 6!.$$
